# Get Element with most children of specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a navigation that looks like this:

```
<div class="sub_navigation">   
    <ul>
        <li>First Level
            <ul>
                <li>Second Level</li>
                <li>Second Level
                    <ul>
                        <li>Third Level</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>First Level
            <ul>
                <li>Second Level</li>
                <li>Second Level
                    <ul>
                        <li>Third Level
                          <ul>
                             <li>Fourth Level</li>
                          </ul>
                       </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Basically, everly li can have an infinite amount of children uls. I need to get the number of the highest level 
For example, right now I'd be looking for the number 4 as the second li has 4 Levels.

I tried two different methods:

First, my own attempt that failed miserably:

```
$count = 1;

$('.sub_navigation > .menu > li').each(function() {
    countChildren($count);
});

function countChildren() {
    $(this).children('ul').each(function() {
        $count++;
        console.log($count);
    });
    return($count);
}
```

Second, a way I took from stack overflow but that didn't work out for me either, only returning 0 everytime:

```
var arr = []; //populate the length of children into this array.
$('.sub_navigation ul').map(function (i) {
    arr[i] = $(this).children('ul').length;
});
var maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math, arr); //get the max value from the array

console.log(maxValue);
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction? I sadly have no idea how to acieve this at all anymore.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `parentsUntil()` like

```js
var temp = $('.sub_navigation li').map(function() {
  return $(this).parentsUntil('.sub_navigation', 'ul').length;
}).get();
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, temp);
snippet.log('Count: ' + max)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub_navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>First Level
      <ul>
        <li>Second Level</li>
        <li>Second Level
          <ul>
            <li>Third Level</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>First Level
      <ul>
        <li>Second Level</li>
        <li>Second Level
          <ul>
            <li>Third Level
              <ul>
                <li>Fourth Level
                  <ul>
                    <li>Fifth Level</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I would check the `ul` in the `parentsUntil` so that the count needs no adjustment.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just tested it and it works like a charm!  @GabyakaG.Petrioli do you mean like this? return $(this).parentsUntil('.sub_navigation', 'ul').length (without the +1)?

Comment: @Sirence yes exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going from top to bottom level you could do it the other way.

Check for each `li` how many `ul` ancestors it has

```
var ulAncestorsPerLi = $( '.sub_navigation li' ).map(function(){
         return $(this).parentsUntil( '.sub_navigation', 'ul' ).length;
    }).get(),
    deepestLevel = Math.max.apply( Math, ulAncestorsPerLi );

alert( deepestLevel );
```

```js
var ulAncestorsPerLi = $('.sub_navigation li').map(function() {
    return $(this).parentsUntil('.sub_navigation', 'ul').length;
  }).get(),
  deepestLevel = Math.max.apply(Math, ulAncestorsPerLi);

alert(deepestLevel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sub_navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>First Level
      <ul>
        <li>Second Level</li>
        <li>Second Level
          <ul>
            <li>Third Level</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>First Level
      <ul>
        <li>Second Level</li>
        <li>Second Level
          <ul>
            <li>Third Level
              <ul>
                <li>Fourth Level</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer also works great but I had to change return parentsUntil( '.sub_navigation', 'ul' ).length; to return $(this).parentsUntil( '.sub_navigation', 'ul' ).length; to get it working. Is either answers faster or performance friendlier than the other?

Comment: @Sirence you are right. in the full-working snippet i had it correct. The answers are the same.

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope it's okay I choose Aruns answers, sadly I can not choose both. Have a nice day!

Comment: you are welcome. Ofcourse it is ok. besides he answered before me.